# How do you solve speed questions while only knowing the time?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> David's father picks him up from school every evening at 6 pm. One day, David was dismissed early at 5 pm. He walked home taking the same route that his father usually drives. When he met his father along the way, he boarded the car and returned home 50 minutes earlier than usual. Given that his father drove at a constant speed and planned to reach the school at 6 pm sharp, how long, in minutes, had he walked before he as picked up by his father?

In this question, we are only given the time which is 6 pm, 5 pm and 50 minutes earlier. From here, I have completely no idea on how to continue doing this. Please help.

*This question is from the 2004 Singapore Mathematical Olympiad for Primary Schools*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

- $X$ be the time duration of a one-way trip to school by car
- $Y$ be the time duration of the one-way trip by car before interception
- $Z$ be the time duration David has walked before interception (what we are asked to solve for)

So by these definitions, David's Dad always leaves at 6h00-X and he and David normally arrive at home at 6h00+X. Now, the new time of arrival is: $$t_{a}= 6h00-X+2Y =6h00+X-50 \text{ min}$$ From which we cannot explicitly tell what $X$ and $Y$ are, but we infer the difference:
$$X-Y = 25\text{ min}$$

Now the time of interception is:
$$t_{i}= 5h00 + Z =6h00-X+ Y$$ 
From which we solve : $Z= 35 \text{ min}$

Comment: You are right that you don't need to know when David's father actually leaves to solve the problem, because the actual crucial equation in your notation is $-60+Z=-X+Y$ (the left side being the time relative to 6:00 that David stops walking and the right side being the time relative to 6:00 that David's father reaches him) which doesn't depend explicitly on $X$. So your answer is the best of the three.

Answer (score 0):

David started walking at $5$ pm.
By walking he saves $50$ minutes of journey by car.

Lets say that David and the car intercepted at point $X$ somewhere between $H$ and $S$. Now distance from $X$ to $S$ and then again to $X$ (kind of a $2$-way trip) was saved. This is equivalent to $50$ minutes of car time. A one-way trip from $S$ to $X$ is $25$ minutes of car time. Therefore the car travelled for $60-25=35$ minutes and David walked for $35$ minutes.

Comment: So the final answer is...?

Comment: $25$ minutes worth of car journey

Comment: So you mean that David walked for $25$ minutes?

Comment: That depends on how fast the car is as compared to Davids walking speed

Comment: Then that doesn't answer the question...

Comment: I editted my answer. I misunderstood the question as to finding the distance walked.

Comment: The "60 minutes" that you are subtracting from is what is not clearly spelled out in the prompt. Certainly David saved 25 minutes of his own car time, but it's not totally obvious that his whole trip was 70 minutes.

Comment: If the car saves $50$ minutes of its two way journey, then time saved on 1 way is $25$ minutes. I subtract that from $60$

Comment: Yes, the 60 part is what isn't clear, because it requires you to assume that David's father leaves at 5 PM, which isn't explicitly stated anywhere.

Comment: Thats absolutely true. The question should have specified that